# converting list of spring service to another Entity as response

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, arraylist

I have a userService

```
entityDTO = (EntityDto) userService.getAllUsersOfCompany(companyId);
```

It will return list of  `UserDTO`

In this list The entity have lot of fields Like (userId,name,address,place.....etc)

But I want only `userId` and `name`.

for that I created one `EntityDto`

```
public class EntityDto {

    private String Id;
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        Id = id;
    }

}
```

Now I need to map `List<EntityDto>`  to `List<UserDTO>`.

Is it possible with dozer mapping ???

Comment: Do it at the hand : iterate on the list and use fields of the entity to create the UserDTO object or use a mapping library (Why not which of Spring as you already use it)

Comment: Yes it's possible with dozer mapping

Comment: Can you please help me for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for Java 8 follow what @TouzeneMohamedWassim mentiened 
but for java < 8 , there is not stream and map in their api

So you should use the traditional loop method  (like creating a method which loop throw your list and returns the new entity ) as below :

```
private static List<EntityDto> convertEntityDto(List<UserDTO> users) {

    List<EntityDto> newList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (UserDTO usr : users) {

        EntityDto entity = new EntityDto();
        entity.setId(usr.getId());
        entity.setName(usr.getName());

        newList.add(entity);
    }

    return newList;
}
```

Then call your method :

```
List<EntityDto> listEntityDTO  = 
    convertEntityDto(serService.getAllUsersOfCompany(companyId));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JAVA8 or +, you can use ***stream*** like this :

```
List<EntityDto> users = new ArrayList<>();
userService.getAllUsersOfCompany(companyId).stream().forEach(
entity -> {
   users.add(new EntityDto(entity.getId(), entity.getName()))
});
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to do in java 7

Comment: yeah ,it's better to use java 8 stream api .

Comment: Or better `List<EntityDto> users = 
 userService.getAllUsersOfCompany(companyId).stream()
        .map(entity -> new EntityDto(entity.getId(), entity.getName()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());`